# React FormEvent<HTMLFormElement> form input props types

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How to make types for form inputs?

```
const Index = () => {
  const handleSubmit = async (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(e.currentTarget.elements.email)
  }

  return (
    <Layout>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input name='email' type='email' autoComplete='email' required />
        <input name='password' type='password' autoComplete='password' required />
        <button type='submit'>Login</button>
      </form>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

Type error:

> Property 'email' does not exist on type 'HTMLFormControlsCollection'.

Comment: ```HTMLFormControlsCollection``` is an array of form elements.. May I know whether you are looking to retrieve the value of email?? If so you could use    ```console.log((e.currentTarget.elements[0] as HTMLInputElement).value);``` ..

Comment: You can do `e.currentTarget.elements[0]` or `e.currentTarget.elements.namedItem('email')` and it will not complain

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here `FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>` will give an array list as `HTMLFormControlsCollection` .

So when you are trying to get the email like this `e.currentTarget.elements.email` it throws the error as,

> Property 'email' does not exist on type 'HTMLFormControlsCollection'.

So to get the value of email, You need to get the email element inside an array as

`e.currentTarget.elements[0]` (as email is first element)

So now we got the email input element and hence let as assign as `HTMLInputElement`.. and to get the value use,

```
console.log((e.currentTarget.elements[0] as HTMLInputElement).value);
```

**Working example:**

> https://codesandbox.io/s/react-with-typescript01-37jc4

**Update:**

As mentioned in the comments section, I have made this update where you could also use,

```
console.log((e.currentTarget.elements.namedItem('email') as HTMLInputElement).value);
```

to get the email value.. But here to get the email value from the array collection I have described with `[0]` ..

**Updated Codesandbox**

> https://codesandbox.io/s/react-with-typescript01-26www

Comment: Just don't think `[0]` would be the best practice in this situation

Comment: @keikai yep, namedItem('email') will be better.

Comment: @RTW, Updated the answer with ```namedItem('email')``` method as well..

Answer (score 3):

If you want to refer to the element you can do `e.currentTarget.elements[0]` or `e.currentTarget.elements.namedItem('email')`

and then you can just access the value.

e.g.

```
const emailElement = e.currentTarget.elements.namedItem('email') as HTMLInputElement
console.log(emailElement.value)
```

References: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/namedItem